# Showing the action of $SO(p,q)$ in the punctured cone of isotropic vectors is transitive

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, group-actions

Consider a real vector space $T$ of dimension $p+q$ with a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form, $B:T\times T\to\mathbb{R}$, with signature $(p,q)$. Define the *cone*
$$
C=\{(x_1,\dots,x_p,x_{p+1},\dots,x_{p+q})\in T\setminus\{0\}: x_1^2+\cdots+x_p^2-x_{p+1}^2-\cdots-x_{p+q}^2=0\},
$$
which is nothing else than the set of isotropic vectors w.r.t. the bilinear form.

I know that if $p=0$ or $q=0$ the cone is empty, so we are considering the cases where $\min\{p,q\}\geq 1$. I also know that this is false for $p=q=1$, while the action of $O(1,1)$ *is* transitive: an explicit computation of $SO(1,1)$ and $C$ easily proves it.

But this must be true for $\min\{p,q\}\geq 1$ and $\max\{p,q\}>1$.

Given two vectors $v,w\in C$ I think the proof should be divided in three different cases:

- $v$ and $w$ are linearly dependent: In this case we can find a two dimensional subspace where the bilinear form has signature $(1,1)$ and choose a basis for which $v=(1,1,0\dots,0)$. In this case we can find an element in $SO(1,1)$ that contracts or expands $v$ to $w$ (even if there is a change of sign).
- $v$ and $w$ are linearly dependent and $B(v,w)=0$. In this case we can find a vector $u\in C$ such that $B(v,u)\neq 0$ and $B(w,u)\neq 0$. Then there are two transformations in $O(1,1)\setminus SO(1,1)$ that take $v$ to $u$ and $u$ to $w$, respectively. Taking the determinant of their composition shows it is in $SO(1,1)$.
- $v$ and $w$ are linearly independent and B$(v,w)\neq 0$. This is where I'm stuck.

I tried showing it for $SO(2,1)$ and $SO(1,2)$ explicitely, but calculating the explicit matrix form of their elements is quite cumbersome. Any other proof or idea is  welcome.

I would also appreciate if someone could tell me if what I've done is correct.

Comment: in (2,2) with $x^2 + y^2 - z^2 - w^2$ you can send $(x,y,z,w)$ to $$ (x \cos \alpha + y \sin \alpha, \; -x \sin \alpha + y \cos \alpha, \; z \cos \beta + w \sin \beta, \; -z \sin \beta + w \cos \beta   )  $$ with independent angles $\alpha, \beta$

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, but I'm afraid I don't see how that helps...

Comment: you can also multiply through by a scalar. If all you want is a transitive action, that should do it. Given your two points, divide by a positive scalar such that the $p$ part (for each)has norm one, $x_1^2 + \cdots + x_p^2 = 1.$ It follows that the $q$ part for each is also one. Independent rotations take one of your scaled points into the other; now divide by the earlier scalar, get back to the original.

Comment: @WillJagy So, first of all. Is my argument about $SO(p,q)$ containing scalar multiplication correct? Also, since $SO(p)$ and $SO(q)$ are in the component of the identity of their respective groups, does that mean the transformation you describe would also lie in the component of the identity of $SO(p,q)$?

Comment: wikipedia says that SO(p,q) must have determinant 1, so scalar multiplication would not be included, and the group action would actually not be transitive. This fits my experience from quadratic forms, we are not preserving the null cone as a set, we are being more specific than that. I suggest you check your sources for exactly what they mean by transitive here: certainly, the group as wikipedia describes it would work on the intersection of the null cone with the standard unit sphere.

Comment: @WillJagy In the end, what I really want to show is that the component of the identity in $SO(p,q)$ acts transitively on $C/ \sim$, where $v\sim w$ if they are linearly dependent. So I think your argument may work for me as well...